# How to do offline-installation of multiple images via podman load/save

Tags: docker, mariadb, podman, docker-compose

I am using an app depending on the image `docker.io/library/mariadb:10.7`. Images can be pulled, and saved in a tarball:

```bsh
podman pull \
  docker.io/photoprism/photoprism:latest \
  docker.io/library/mariadb:10.7

podman save \
  -o images.tar \
  docker.io/photoprism/photoprism:latest \
  docker.io/library/mariadb:10.7
```

and installed on a different system offline via `load`:

```bsh
docker load -i images.tar
```

The above command runs successfully and I can see images via `podman images`:

```
REPOSITORY                       TAG         IMAGE ID      CREATED     SIZE
docker.io/photoprism/photoprism  latest      3bd51d37096b  4 days ago  1.33 GB
docker.io/library/mariadb        10.7        3bd51d37096b  4 days ago  1.33 GB
```

Starting `docker-compose.yml` via `docker-compose up -d` does not result in an immediately apparent error. But `journalctl -f` shows me an endless error loop of starting and restarting mariadb container attempts:

```bsh
container init (image=docker.io/library/mariadb:10.7...
container start(image=docker.io/library/mariadb:10.7...
container died (image=docker.io/library/mariadb:10.7,...
container restart(image=docker.io/library/mariadb:10.7,...
container init(image=docker.io/library/mariadb:10.7,...
#... and so on
```

Now, this is important: Pulling images via `docker-compose pull`/`podman pull` directly online and otherwise keeping the above steps - just within the same system - works fine!

Hence I guess, this must be an issue with `podman save` / `podman load` of different machines (same architecture, Fedora).

Having read [this issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/13139) I tried

```bsh
podman unshare podman load -i images.tar
```

without success.

One last note: podman is run in user-space, if that should matter:

```bsh
export DOCKER_HOST="unix://$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/podman/podman.sock
systemctl --user enable --now podman.socket
```

How might I debug this issue further? What could be the cause (user-space permissions,...) and an appropriate fix?

Answer (score 1):

After more investigation: You need to add the `-m` flag, when saving multiple images in a tarball.

```
podman save -m -o images.tar \
  docker.io/photoprism/photoprism:latest \
  docker.io/library/mariadb:10.7
```

> -m, --multi-image-archive
> Interpret additional arguments as images not tags and create a multi-image-archive (only for docker-archive)

More infos: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/2669